# How to use Windows login as web app login?

Tags: php, node.js, wordpress, amazon-web-services

I want to develop a web app using php and wordpress or nodejs my requirement the login on this app will be depend on windows login of a client how can we achieve it as SSO? wordpress is preferable will use AWS

Comment: Can you demonstrate any effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I am new to this, I have searched it on net but not able to understand if it is achievable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop this application in NodejS then node-ntlm-auth can be used for sso **[https://www.npmjs.com/package/ntlm-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-ldapauth)** if there are multiple domains in single forest then it need to be specified in the application or for simple LDAP authentication you can use **[passport-ldapauth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-ldapauth)**.